# int64_t pointer cast to AVX2 intrinsic _m256i

Tags: c++, pointers, avx2

Hello I have a strange problem with AVX2 intrinsics. I create a pointer to a _m256i vector with a int64_t* cast. I then assign a value by dereferencing the pointer. The strange thing is that the value isn't observed in the vector variable, unless i run a few cout statements after it. The pointer and the vector have the same memory address and dereferencing the pointer produces the correct value, but the vector does not.  What am I missing?

```
// Vector Variable 
__m256i R_A0to3 = _mm256_set1_epi32(0xFFFFFFFF);

int64_t *ptr = NULL;
for(int m=0; m<4; m++){
    // Cast pointer to vector type
    ptr = (int64_t*)&R_A0to3;

    cout<<"ptr_ADDRESS:      "<<ptr<<endl;
    cout<<"&R_A0to3_ADDRESS: "<<&R_A0to3<<endl;

    // access
    ptr[m] = (int64_t) m_array[m];

    // generic function that prints out register
    print_mm256_reg<int64_t>(R_A0to3, "R_A0to3");
    cout<<"m_array: "<< m_array[m]<<std::ends;

    // Additional print statements
    cout<<"ptr[m]: "<< ptr[m]<<std::endl;
    cout<<"ptr[0]: "<< ptr[0]<<std::endl;
    cout<<"ptr[1]: "<< ptr[1]<<std::endl;
    cout<<"ptr[2]: "<< ptr[2]<<std::endl;
    cout<<"ptr[3]: "<< ptr[3]<<std::endl;
    print_mm256_reg<int64_t>(R_A0to3, "R_A0to3");
}
```

---

```
Output:
 ptr_ADDRESS      0x7ffd9313e880
 &R_A0to3_ADDRESS 0x7ffd9313e880
 m_array: 8
 printing reg -    R_C0to3    -1|  -1|  -1|  -1|
 printing reg -    R_D0to3    -1|  -1|  -1|  -1|

Output with Additional print statements:
ptr_ADDRESS      0x7ffd36359e20
&R_A0to3_ADDRESS 0x7ffd36359e20
printing reg -    R_A0to3     -1|  -1|  -1|  -1|
m_array: 8

ptr[0]: 8
ptr[1]: -1
ptr[2]: -1
ptr[3]: -1
printing reg -    R_A0to3      8|  -1|  -1|  -1|
```

Comment: What compiler is this? I believe this is one of those corner cases in GCC where a strict-aliasing violation will actually cause problems even though they're not supposed to. (SIMD types are declared `__may_alias__`.) Have you tried disabling strict-aliasing? Does `-Wstrict-aliasing` make it complain?

Comment: @Mysticial: Perhaps the compiler gives up on keeping the variables coherent because the program has undefined behaviour?  `ptr[m]` for m=4..9 accesses outside `__m256i R_A0to3`.  In any case, this is a silly way to use vectors.  Don't do this.  If you really want to store to a buffer and modify a vector, write code that does that and reloads the vector afterwards.  Or possibly use a union.  Type-punning with pointer-casts is not a good idiom.

Comment: @PeterCordes Aha, you're right! I didn't see it was going out-of-bounds.

Comment: Sorry, I removed a bunch of code to make it readable here on stack but I guess i introduced a bug.  In reality, m is never greater than 3. I'll edit the post for clarity.

The compiler is g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413. I added -Wstrict-aliasing.

Comment: So I figured out the problem, kinda. I was compiling with -O3 and -O2. Compiling with -O1 however, makes the problem go away. 

Any insight into what could be causing the problem?

Comment: @Mystical. After some googling of unions I found out about this intrinsic function _mm256_insert_epi64 (__m256i a, __int64 i, const int index) which pretty much avoids this pointer casting. Thanks

Comment: The -O1/-O2 difference could point at -fstrict-aliasing indeed. But really, without a [mcve], this is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using the `_mm256_extract_epi64` and `_mm256_insert_epi64` intrinsics when you need occasional access to individual elements. If you need to access all elements from the vector, consider using `_mm256_store_si256` and `_mm256_lddqu_si256` to store and load it. These intrinsics are less likely to rely on undefined behavior and they are transparent as to the machine instructions being generated (and thus as to the performance).

Comment: If you need all elements as separate scalars, storing to a local array is not a bad option.  You'll probably get better code than with extracts.  Or use a union for type-punning instead of pointer-casting, since IIRC, GNU C guarantees that union-based type-punning works.  (I think it's safe on other x86 compilers that don't support the GNU C extensions, too.)

Comment: "Or use a union for type-punning instead of pointer-casting, since IIRC, GNU C guarantees that union-based type-punning works. (I think it's safe on other x86 compilers that don't support the GNU C extensions, too.)" In this case, I think you have little idea how the compiler will implement it... probably with stores and loads though I could be wrong. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: [gcc stores/reloads, clang uses extract instructions](https://godbolt.org/g/oqFjDE).  That's just a missed-optimization from gcc; but IDK how soon it'll be fixed.  Obviously either way is pretty low performance (esp. store/modify/reload store-forwarding failure), so should mainly be used for things like debug-prints.  I hadn't realized `_mm256_extract_epi64` existed / worked on upper elements, because [`vpextrq`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXTRB:PEXTRD:PEXTRQ.html) doesn't, so that's handy.  Also, `_mm256_lddqu_si256` is pointless; just use `loadu`.  (or `load` if aligned, I guess).

Comment: " Also, _mm256_lddqu_si256 is pointless; just use loadu. (or load if aligned, I guess)." I have not come across a case where load as opposed to loadu or lddq was faster. I also unaware of any performance difference between lddqu and loadu, but the two exists and Intel says lddqu can be faster (something I have never observed but I keep the faith).