# what's the difference between _mm256_lddqu_si256 and _mm256_loadu_si256

Tags: x86, simd, intrinsics, avx, micro-optimization

I had been using `_mm256_lddqu_si256` based on an example I found online. Later I discovered `_mm256_loadu_si256`. The Intel Intrinsics guide only states that the `lddqu` version may perform better when crossing a cache line boundary. What might be the advantages of `loadu`? In general how are these functions different?

Comment: Oops, I forgot I'd already written most of the historical stuff about non-AVX `lddqu` [in an earlier answer about `_mm_loadu_si128`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370622/a-faster-integer-sse-unalligned-load-thats-rarely-used).  (Including the same links, because I remembered to search for the same things.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**There's no reason to ever use `_mm256_lddqu_si256`**, consider it a synonym for `_mm256_loadu_si256`.  `lddqu` only exists for historical reasons as x86 evolved towards having better unaligned vector load support, and CPUs that support the AVX version run them identically.  There's no AVX512 version.

[Compilers do still respect the `lddqu` intrinsic](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A%0A__m256i+foo(__m256i+*p)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm256_lddqu_si256(p)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A__m256i+bar(__m256i+*p)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm256_loadu_si256(p)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,m:65.44554455445545,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:34.554455445544555,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) and emit that instruction, so you could use it if you want your code to run identically but have a different checksum or machine code bytes.

---

No x86 microarchitectures run `vlddqu` any differently from `vmovdqu`.  I.e. the two opcodes probably decode to the same internal uop on all AVX CPUs.  They probably always will, unless some very-low-power or specialized microarchitecture comes along without efficient unaligned vector loads (which have been a thing since Nehalem).  Compilers never use `vlddqu` when auto-vectorizing.

**`lddqu` was different from `movdqu` on Pentium 4.  See [History of … one CPU instructions: Part 1. LDDQU/movdqu explained](https://web.archive.org/web/20191122223132/https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/04/16/history-of-one-cpu-instructions-part-1-lddqumovdqu-explained).**

`lddqu` is allowed to (and on P4 *does do*) two aligned 16B loads and takes a window of that data.  `movdqu` architecturally only ever loads from the expected 16 bytes.  **This has implications for store-forwarding**: if you're loading data that was just stored with an unaligned store, use `movdqu` because store-forwarding only works for loads that are fully contained within a previous store.  But otherwise you generally always wanted to use `lddqu`.  (This is why they didn't just make `movdqu` always use "the good way", and instead introduced a new instruction for programmers to worry about.  But luckily for us, they changed the design so we don't have to worry about which unaligned load instruction to use anymore.)

It also has implications for correctness of observable behaviour on UnCacheable (UC) or Uncacheable Speculate Write-combining (UCSW, aka WC) memory types (which might have MMIO registers behind them.)

---

There's no code-size difference in the two asm instructions:

```
  # SSE packed-single instructions are shorter than SSE2 integer / packed-double
  4000e3:       0f 10 07                movups xmm0, [rdi]   

  4000e6:       f2 0f f0 07             lddqu  xmm0, [rdi]
  4000ea:       f3 0f 6f 07             movdqu xmm0, [rdi]

  4000ee:       c5 fb f0 07             vlddqu xmm0, [rdi]
  4000f2:       c5 fa 6f 07             vmovdqu xmm0, [rdi]
  # AVX-256 is the same as AVX-128, but with one more bit set in the VEX prefix
```

---

On Core2 and later, there's no reason to use `lddqu`, but also no downside vs. `movdqu`.  Intel dropped the special `lddqu` stuff for Core2, so both options suck equally.

On Core2 specifically, avoiding cache-line splits in software with two aligned loads and SSSE3 `palignr` is sometimes a win vs. `movdqu`, especially on 2nd-gen Core2 (Penryn) where `palignr` is only one shuffle uop instead of 2 on Merom/Conroe.  (Penryn widened the shuffle execution unit to 128b).

**See Dark Shikaris's 2009 Diary Of An x264 Developer blog post: [Cacheline splits, take two](http://web.archive.org/web/20120417184641/http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/96) for more about unaligned-load strategies back in the bad old days**.

The generation after Core2 is Nehalem, where `movdqu` is a single uop instruction with dedicated hardware support in the load ports.  It's still useful to tell compilers when pointers are aligned (especially for auto-vectorization, and especially without AVX), but it's not a performance disaster for them to just use `movdqu` everywhere, especially if the data is in fact aligned at run-time.

---

I don't know why Intel even made an AVX version of `lddqu` at all.  I guess it's simpler for the decoders to just treat that opcode as an alias for `movdqu` / `vmovdqu` in all modes (with legacy SSE prefixes, or with AVX128 / AVX256), instead of having that opcode decode to something else with VEX prefixes.

All current AVX-supporting CPUs have efficient hardware unaligned-load / store support that handles it as optimally as possible.  e.g. when the data is aligned at runtime, there's exactly zero performance difference vs. `vmovdqa`.

This was *not* the case before Nehalem; `movdqu` and `lddqu` used to decode to multiple uops to handle potentially-misaligned addresses, instead of putting hardware support for that right in the load ports where a single uop can activate it instead of faulting on unaligned addresses.

However, [Intel's ISA ref manual entry for `lddqu`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LDDQU.html) says the 256b version can load up to 64 bytes (implementation dependent):

> This instruction may improve performance relative to (V)MOVDQU if the source operand crosses a cache line boundary. In situations that require the data loaded by (V)LDDQU be modified and stored to the same location, use (V)MOVDQU or (V)MOVDQA instead of (V)LDDQU. To move a double quadword to or from memory locations that are known to be aligned on 16-byte boundaries, use the (V)MOVDQA instruction.

IDK how much of that was written deliberately, and how much of that just came from prepending `(V)` when updating the entry for AVX.  I don't think Intel's optimization manual recommends really using `vlddqu` anywhere, but I didn't check.

**There is no AVX512 version of `vlddqu`**, so I think that means Intel has decided that an alternate-strategy unaligned load instruction is no longer useful, and isn't even worth keeping their options open.