# operand type mismatch for `lddqu' with an __int128 "=r" destination

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

I need to move 128 bit value from the address [rsi - 0x80] to the dest variable below using instruction lddqu, and I am encountering the error "operand type mismatch for `lddqu'". I know there are previous questions on stackoverflow using lower operand sizes but what suffix should I use with the instruction to be able to get the value at that address in the variable.

```
 __int128 dst = 0, src = 0;
asm volatile ("lddqu -0x80(%%rsi), %0\n\t"
        : "=r" (dst)
        : "r" (src));
```

Just to give an overview of the entire problem, this is only one instruction that is part of a larger graph algorithm that finds shortest path between two vertices. src variable is redundant and can be removed if it adds ambiguity. I am designing a hardware prefetcher (in a processor simulator) to predict future memory addresses based on the currently accessed addresses. Once I can get an address in a variable like dst, I have a technique that automatically predicts the future address and triggers the memory request for that address.

A larger version of the pattern is a sequence of loads and store, and looks like this:

```
  lddqu  xmm0,[rsi-0x80]
  movdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-0x80],xmm0
  lddqu  xmm0,[rsi-0x70]
  movdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-0x70],xmm0
  lddqu  xmm0,[rsi-0x60]
  movdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-0x60],xmm0
  lddqu  xmm0,[rsi-0x50]
  movdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-0x50],xmm0
```

Now, I am working on how to get the inline asm working with Intel syntax.

Comment: You should be using intrinsics for this, especially if you don't already know how to use GNU C inline asm.  Like `__m128i tmp = _mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*)&src );` then you can `_mm_storeu_si128` into dst if you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info.  Or obviously just `dst = src` and let the compiler do its job.

Comment: re: your edit: compilers generally don't need help using XMM registers to copy 16-byte objects around.  Or even using YMM registers to copy them in pairs.  If you're worried about `lddqu` for more efficient unaligned loads, that only ever mattered on P4 ([A faster integer SSE unalligned load that's rarely used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38370622)).  On all other x86 CPUs, `lddqu` and `movdqu` decode to the same internal uops.  Seems like you really just want `memcpy` or `memmove` if you have some contiguous copying to do.

Comment: Re: Intel syntax in inline asm: [How to set gcc to use intel syntax permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38953951)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lddqu` can only load into a vector register, not a general-purpose register. Use `=x` in place of `=r` for `dst`'s constraint.

Also, your source looks suspicious, since you're ignoring `src` and just loading from an arbitrary offset of a register that you know nothing about the content of.

Look at the compiler-generated asm around your asm statement to see how the compiler gets `__int128 dst` back into memory or integer registers after you force it to be in an XMM register, for example on https://godbolt.org/, especially with -O2 optimization enabled.

Using inline asm like this is probably even worse for efficiency than using SSE intrinsics like `_mm_loadu_si128` - See also https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Comment: Using =x solved the issue.  I have added a broader context if that can be helpful for any future reader.